# How can I improve the logic and data management of my web form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an interactive web form with conditions based on values selected by the user. Certain form fields will appear depending on what value is selected in the first field question (in my case example, 'Your office').

Since I am a beginner to JavaScript, I am using a basic `if/else` statement. I am looking for guidance on how to make my logic more efficient/easier to maintain.

**My question: 
What's a better way to write this? Maybe use JavaScript objects? if so, how?  In my real world example, I have over 70+ offices with various properties (some offices publish books, some publish magazines, some none, some all, etc!)...so I am doing a lot of hiding and revealing of various div elements using CSS...and depending on what selection the user makes in the first field will determine what that user will see in the next fields. 
Is there a better way to update and maintain the data?**

*Note: I am unable to use a database for content management*

Here's an example of how I am approaching the logic:

Also, a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/g89xqzr6/) of the below code:

> HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="" id="my_form">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="form-group">
        <label for="office" class="control-label">
          <h2>Your office:</h2>
        </label>
        <select name="" id="office" class="form-control input-lg" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled>-Select-</option>
          <option value="abc">ABC</option>
          <option value="def">DEF</option>
          <option value="ghi">GHI</option>
          <option value="123">123</option>
        </select>
      </section>
    </div>

    <section id="productType" class="form-group hidden">
      <label for="productType" class="control-label">
        <h2>Product Type:</h2>
      </label>
      <div id="productsList">

        <div id="books_radio" class="radio">
          <label for="productType">
            <input type="radio" name="productType" id="books" value="books">Books
          </label>
        </div>
        <div id="magazines_radio" class="radio">
          <label for="productType">
            <input type="radio" name="productType" id="magazines" value="magazines">Magazines
          </label>
        </div>
        <div id="comics_radio" class="radio">
          <label for="productType">
            <input type="radio" name="productType" id="comics" value="comics">Comics
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label for="productType">
            <input type="radio" name="productType" id="special" value="special">Special
          </label>
        </div>

      </div><!--/#productsList -->
    </section><!--/#productType -->

   <section id="books_form" class="alert alert-success hidden">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" name="books-button" role="button">Books order form</a>
   </section> 

   <section id="mag_form" class="alert alert-success hidden">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" name="mag-button" role="button">Magazine order form</a>
   </section>

   <section id="comics_form" class="alert alert-success hidden">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" name="comics-button" role="button">Comics order form</a>
   </section>

   <section id="special_form" class="alert alert-success hidden">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" name="special-button" role="button">Special order form</a>
   </section>

   <section id="jira_jump" class="alert alert-success hidden">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" name="jira-button" role="button">Your office is part of JIRA -- click now</a>
   </section>

  </form>
</div><!--/.container -->
```

> My JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

var productType = $('#my_form input:radio[name=productType]');

var books_form = $('#books_form');
var mag_form = $('#mag_form');
var comics_form = $('#comics_form');
var special_form = $('#special_form');
var jira_jump = $('#jira_jump');

var allForms = books_form.add(mag_form).add(comics_form).add(special_form).add(jira_jump);

$('#office').on('change', function() {

    var officeValue = $('#office').val();

  switch (officeValue) {
    case 'abc':
    case 'def':
        productType.prop('checked', false);//clears radio values of products
      $('#productType').removeClass('hidden'); //hide the productType parent div
      allForms.addClass('hidden'); //hide all form links
        break;
     default: 
        productType.prop('checked', false);
      $('#productType').removeClass('hidden');
      allForms.addClass('hidden');
        break;
  }

  productType.on('change', function() {

    var productValue = this.value;

    if ( (officeValue === 'abc' || officeValue === 'def') && (productValue === 'books' || productValue === 'magazines' || productValue === 'comics') ) {
        allForms.addClass('hidden');
      jira_jump.removeClass('hidden');

    } else if (productValue === 'special') {
            allForms.addClass('hidden');
        special_form.removeClass('hidden');
        jira_jump.addClass('hidden');
    } else if (productValue === 'books') {
            allForms.addClass('hidden');
        books_form.removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (productValue == 'magazines') {
        allForms.addClass('hidden');
      mag_form.removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (productValue === 'comics') {
        allForms.addClass('hidden');
        comics_form.removeClass('hidden');
    }

  }); //end producttype event

});//end office change event
```

Comment: Might be better over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unless I missed something it seems like a very subjective question which most likely leads to opinions and discussions as they are many ways to write the code. Not sure it falls within the context of SO's [**On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in this case it would be better use a MCV/MVVM framework. A MVC/MVVM framework helps you a lot with interacting between view, data and logic.